# Error interrupting when installing redis on 'Elastic Beanstalk EC2'

Tags: amazon-web-services, installation, redis

I conducted CI/CD with AWS Elastic Beanstalk + github action,
Error stopping progress while trying to install redis..

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonElastiCache/latest/red-ug/nodes-connecting.html

I'm referring to this article and proceeding with it. If you execute the 'make' command during the 'EC2 redis-cli' installation stage

As shown below, the execution stops and it does not proceed further..

[stopped execution image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NnU5k.png)

The EB also changes to an error state due to this stopping phenomenon.

[EB also changes to an error state](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TZFmG.png)

I'd like some advice on how to resolve it. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

With someone else's advice yesterday, I share how I solved it!

You don't necessarily have to install redis-cli directly on the EC2 server.

You can connect to the project right after making ElastiCache Redis!

When running locally, it is said that it is not possible to link with the Elasticache Redis host address (-> I was not aware of this..)

Reference : https://kth990303.tistory.com/450 (-> It's Korean.)

So you put the ElastiCache endpoint as the 'redishost' value,

+) Example images

[Aws ElastiCache redis endpoint](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Eo1NZ.png)

[Write redis endpoint to Spirngboot project's 'application.yml'](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WIdxl.png)

[Add values to aws Elastic Beanstalk Environment Variables](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZmMct.png)

If I run this locally, it won't work... If I deploy this as EB and then test it, it worked well!

+) When running locally, it can only be tested on a local Redis server

I'm sharing this because I think people like me who are new to the redis setup might get lost!